# How to explain and element of the 1/2+1/4+... series proof

Tags: sequences-and-series

I came accross this [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_+_1/4_+_1/8_+_1/16_+_%E2%8B%AF) article on the infinite series $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} + \ldots$ and while reading the proof I stumbled on how do you get this:

[image]

I do understand that after multiplying both sides of the equation, you can simplify each fraction, and as a result get $1 + S_n + \frac{2}{2^n}$ on one side. But how do you get $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ instead of that?

Comment: Dividing the numerator & the denominator of each term by $2$

Comment: Why not see what happens when $n$ is, say, three?

Comment: @GerryMyerson good point, it didn't occur to me to use arithmetic to figure this one out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{2}{2^{n}} = \frac 2 {2 \cdot 2^{n - 1}} = \frac{1}{2^{n - 1}}$$

by the definition of an exponent.

Comment: Thanks, my math is rusty :) it is all clear now.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can get that by using the powers laws.

$\frac{a^{m}}{a^{n}}=\frac{1}{a^{n-m}}$.